# ddclient Returns 7000 Error Connecting to Cloudflare

Tags: cloudflare, dynamic-dns, ddclient

I am setting up DDNS using ddclient. I have searched the web, and nothing seems to help. I looked up examples, and I don't see what's going wrong. I tried using both api.cloudflare.com/client/v4 and www.cloudflare.com.
I am recieving these error messages:

```
RECEIVE:  HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
RECEIVE:  Date: Tue, 07 Apr 2020 12:04:43 GMT
RECEIVE:  Content-Type: application/json
RECEIVE:  Connection: close
RECEIVE:  Set-Cookie: __cfduid=dff567699cbfb04f2f63c38512956a4e01586261083; expires=Thu, 07-May-20 12:04:43 GMT; path=/; domain=.api.cloudflare.com; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
RECEIVE:  CF-Ray: 58039cdd1e84ff90-BOS
RECEIVE:  Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
RECEIVE:  Expires: Sun, 25 Jan 1981 05:00:00 GMT
RECEIVE:  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
RECEIVE:  CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
RECEIVE:  Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
RECEIVE:  Pragma: no-cache
RECEIVE:  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
RECEIVE:  X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
RECEIVE:  Server: cloudflare
RECEIVE:  
RECEIVE:  {"success":false,"errors":[{"code":7000,"message":"No route for that URI"}],"messages":[],"result":null}
```

This is what ddclient.conf looks like:

```
daemon=300
ssl=yes
protocol=cloudflare
use=web
server=api.cloudflare.com/client/v4
login=foo@foodomain.com
password=correctglobalapikey
zone=skiscratcher.com
pi.skiscratcher.com
```

Comment: What diagnostics or fixes have you tried so far?